# A logical function problem

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function

f(a,n)=nth power of a .If f(a,n-1)=f(a,n)-1,then a+n=?
My try:
I tried to form an equation and proceed with that further.But I ended up with an absurd conclusion!Here is what I did:
Here,
          f(a,n)=a^n ... ... ... ... ...(i)
So,    f(a,n-1)=a^(n-1)... ... ...(ii)
As the problem says,
       f(a,n-1)=f(a,n)-1
or,   a^(n-1)=(a^n) -1
or,   log a based [a^(n-1)]=log a based [(a^n) -1]  ;(By taking a based log on both sides of the equation)
or,   log a based [a^(n-1)]=log a based (a^n) -log a based(1)
or,  n-1=n-0
or,  -1=0
I don't know what is the correct sollution and whether I did any mistake or not .Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear, but I'll guess that $a,n$ are required to be natural numbers.  Absent an assumption of that form there is unlikely to be a unique solution.

First note that we can rule out the case where both $a,n$ are $>1$.  Indeed in that case we'd deduce that $a\,|\,1$, a contradiction.

If $a=1$ the equation is impossible.

If $n=1$ we get $1=a^1-1\implies a = 2$.

Thus, $(a,n)=(2,1)$ is the only solution, and we get $a+n=3$.